# Write unit test for onTouch() android

Tags: android, junit

I am having a text field in my project and associated `setOnTouchListener` with that. In `onTouch()` I am performing the intended action after clicking on that text field.

I need to write unit test case for `onTouch()`. Can anyone help me?

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

        final Intent intent;

        switch (v.getId()) { 

            case R.id.xyz: 
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.xyz))); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                break;

            case R.id.abc: 
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.abc))); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                break; 

            default: 
                break;

        } 

        return false; 
}
```

Comment: Extract the logic inside ouTouch() in a method of your model classes and test this method. Actually, you don't want to test if onTouch event is fired.

Comment: actually i need to pass parameters to the method the object of textView which is inside the project and MotionEvent class. i am unable to use them

Comment: Can you show the code that you want to test?

Comment: public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  final Intent intent ;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.xyz:
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.xyz)));
         startActivity(intent);
         break;
        case R.id.abc:
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.abc)));
         startActivity(intent);
         break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the method i found was :

- get required View from the intended activity using findViewById
- Create object of that activity
- call onTouch(**view,null**)
- no need to take care regarding motion Event's object because its not getting used in this unit test

Comment: can give example

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by, creating variable object of OnTouchListener in activity. In test, called onTouch on that object.

```
    MotionEvent motionEvent = mock(MotionEvent.class);
    when(motionEvent.getAction()).thenReturn(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
    subject.onTouchListener.onTouch(subject,motionEvent);
```

Comment: Ooh with org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0 that throws "Mockito cannot mock/spy because : - final class"! Because, you know, static type checking is always more important than automated tests...